# A matrix of odd order $\geq 7$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n \geq7$ be an odd number. Let $A=[a_{i,j}]$ be an $n \times n$ matrix such that $$a_{i,i+1}=a_{n,1}=1$$ for all $1\leq i \leq n-1$ and $$a_{ij}=0$$ for all other pairs of $(i,j)$. Then which of the following is true:

$(a) \ 1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

$(b) \ -1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

$(c) \ A$ has at least one eigenvalue with multiplicity $\geq 2$.

$(d) \ A$ has no real eigenvalue.

I have been able to show that $(a)$ is true and obviously $(d)$ is false. I'm having trouble with parts $(b)$ and $(c)$.  I think $(b)$ should be false because $det(A+I)\neq0$ but I haven't been able to show this rigorously. With $(c)$, I don't know how we go about proving something about multiplicity without the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A^n=I$. As $n$ is odd, $(-1)^n\ne 1$, so (b) is false. As $X^n-1$ hsa $n$ distinct roots in $\Bbb C$, (c) is false.